# A property of Gaussian distribution function

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

Suppose $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}\,dt.$ Prove that for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $\lambda\in[0,1],$

$$\Phi^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)c}^{\lambda b+(1-\lambda)d} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} \, dt\right) \ge\lambda\Phi^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_a^b e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}\,dt \right) + (1-\lambda) \Phi^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_c^d e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} \, dt\right)$$

I try to prove it with the idea that if $f''(x)\le 0,$ then $f$ is a concave funtion and $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda y))\ge\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$. But we cannot do the addition operation with the integration.